# vbscript print instance values one after another

Tags: arrays, vbscript

This is my code:

```
`strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\WMI") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM MSFC_FCAdapterHBAAttributes")
For each objItem in colItems 
        Wscript.Echo "Active: " & objItem.Active(0)
Next`
```

And I get an output like this:

```
`Active: True` <br/>
`Active: True`
```

But I need to get the output: `Active: True, True`

Could someone help me with this?

This query will work only if `SAN` is connected to the server but you can use any other class for example.

-KAKA-

Comment: For each instance in colItems, you are running `wscript.echo` which includes a line break. You would need to do something like this: `strActive = "Active: " For each objItem in colItems strActive = strActive & objItem.Active(0) & ", " Next wscript.echo strActive`

Comment: i think i provided a bad example. it is not just about a line break. there are multiple values for each instance. for example here two instances and values i am getting is like:

`Instance 1:

A = 1
B = 1.5
C=2.0
D=2.5`

`Instance 2:

A = ABC
B = XYZ
C = XXX
D = YYY`

<\br>and what i want is two print the values of both instance together for same objectitem

A = 1, ABC
B = 1.5, XYZ
C= 2, XYZ

and so on

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `MSFC_FCAdapterHBAAttributes`, but under what circumstances are your properties going to be that different per instance? You'll probably need to use a multi-dimensional array with one dimension the size of the number of instances and the other dimension the size of the number of properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable to store them, below used **strActives**

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\WMI")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSFC_FCAdapterHBAAttributes")
strActives = "" ' <-- Empty String here
For Each objItem In colItems
    If Len(strActives) > 0 Then strActives = strActives & ", " ' Append a comma if it is not empty
    strActives = strActives & objItem.Active(0) ' Append the value
Next
' Here only echo if the strActives is not empty
If Len(strActives) > 0 Then Wscript.Echo "Active: " & strActives
```

Comment: And how can i store each value in different variable instead of keep appending it in single variable? -KAKA-

Comment: There are many ways and depends on your need, e.g. Look for `Array`, `ReDim Preserve`, or [Dictionary Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) or [ArrayList Class from .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx)